# Can't Access Location Outside Geocode

Tags: google-maps, geocoding

So I'm using google maps API and I want to get the location result of a geocode. This is what I've got at the moment:

```
var pinProperties = {};
geocoder.geocode( {"address": address}, function(results, status) {
    if (status == google.maps.GeocoderStatus.OK) {
        pinProperties.markerPos = results[0].geometry.location;
    }
    else if (status === "ZERO_RESULTS") {
        pinProperties.markerPos = map.getCenter();
    }
    else {
        alert("Geocode was not successful for the following reason: " + status);
    }
});
console.log(pinProperties.markerPos);
```

However, pinProperties.markerPos returns undefined, even if one of the first two conditions is met. I need to be able to access the location from outside the geocode. Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Geocoding is asynchonous.  You need to use the returned data inside the callback function.  The code below should log a value for pinProperties.markerPos (unless the operation status is not "OK")

```
var pinProperties = {};
geocoder.geocode( {"address": address}, function(results, status) {
    if (status == google.maps.GeocoderStatus.OK) {
        pinProperties.markerPos = results[0].geometry.location;
    }
    else if (status === "ZERO_RESULTS") {
        pinProperties.markerPos = map.getCenter();
    }
    else {
        alert("Geocode was not successful for the following reason: " + status);
    }
    console.log(pinProperties.markerPos);
});
```

Comment: Thanks, so can I clarify, is there no way that I can use the pinProperties.markerPos outside the callback function?

Comment: You can, but you have to know that it is available.  The easiest way to know that is it is available when the callback function runs.